# When to split a model into two separate ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model called `Price` with the following columns:

```
create_table :prices do |t|
   t.decimal :cost
   t.integer :product_id
   t.integer :store_id
   t.decimal :cost_per_unit
   t.decimal :unit_amount
   t.string  :unit
end
```

In my application a Price can either have the `cost` column used or the other 3, `cost per unit`, `unit amount` and `unit`. Since I have this rule, would it be wise to create another model called `PricePerUnit` or `UnitPrice`? Right now I plan on just using the Price model and two separate forms. What would you do? What would be better in the long run if I plan on having columns that deal specifically with these two different price types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having nullable columns isn't really nice, specially if you plan on querying for them. If having separate classes (and tables) won't make your life more difficult I'd surely create two different classes (and tables) to handle these cases.

If you don't plan on querying for these columns and it's simpler to have one single class, then I don't see a lot of improvements on doing it.